# Having a hard time setup domain controller in HyperV network

Tags: active-directory

I have spent two days trying to troubleshoot the problem but couldnt get any progress.

I have installed a HyperV server (Windows 2012) and trying to build a network from there. The network I am going to build is an internel network. So I created a virtual switch for the internal network.

Then I started to install a Windows 2008 r2 server. I added the role as AD DS and promoted it to a Domain controller with DNS enabled.

However, the DNS service throws a warning : `the dns server is waiting for active directory domain services (AD DS) to signal that the initial sync... 4013` . So I am assuming my Active directory is not setup properly.

I have read through a few tutorial on how to setup a domain controlelr and I have no idea what I had done wrong.

- I have disabled ipv6
- Using static ipv4 address
- I have set the DNS to itself
- Default gateway is left blank
- I have another windows 7 VM and I am not able to join the CORP domain
- I ran `nslookup corp.ftw.com` on the windows7 machine and it returned the name without addresses.

Below are attached trouble shoot output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-VSGC8R1UJA7
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : corp.ftw.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : corp.ftw.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-F5-AA-06
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.67.86(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
PS C:\Users\Administrator> netstat -an | select-string ":53 "

  TCP    127.0.0.1:53           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    169.254.67.86:53       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::1]:53               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  UDP    127.0.0.1:53           *:*
  UDP    169.254.67.86:53       *:*
  UDP    [::1]:53               *:*


PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: You don't have configured Network.

Comment: @AlexanderT Hi, do you mind to explain more? I have configured the static ip address, isnt that a configured network?

Comment: See your `ipconfig` output. There is `   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.67.86(Preferred)`, it's not configured IP.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Ipconfig from your DC or Win 7 machine? the IP Settings are not correct. It is using a 169.254.0.0 address this is an APIPA address and indicates that the VM cant get and address form a DHCP server or you have configured a duplicate IP Address on the VM it will also show up as a 168.254.0.0 address. Either way taka a look at your IP Addressing scheme.

I would use the 192.168.0.0/24 address as your network address and maybe give your DC the 192.168.0.1/24 IP address. you are correct to point the DNS at 127.0.0.1. on the client point the DNS server address at 192.168.0.1

## Not relevant for your problem but worth taking note of

DCs will often have Default gateways, there is no need to disable IPv6 and also DCs don't need static IP addresses as long as they can get an address from a DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will have a look and get back to you soon.